Docker directory becomes empty when binded
I'm currently learning docker, aiming to containerize most of my projects in my home server. I was able to create an image and make it work. However, when I mount/bind the container, the directory I'm trying to mount becomes empty and the container stops working properly because the directory within the container becomes empty as well.
docker-compose.yml
services:
    server:
        container_name: server
        platform: linux/amd64
        image: private/image
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./container:/var/www
        ports:
            - "10001:8080"

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "vendor/autoload.php" ]; then
    composer install --no-progress --no-interaction
fi

php-fpm -D
nginx -g "daemon off;"

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.1-fpm as stage-php

# set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# install dependencies
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y .... nginx

# install php extensions and cleanup
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd .... zip \
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && apt clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set default user and group
RUN usermod --uid 1000 www-data \
    && groupmod --gid 1000 www-data

# composer and install
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www
COPY --from=composer:2.7.2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# transfer custom configs
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./docker/php/zz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/php/entrypoint.sh /app-container-entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /app-container-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app-container-entrypoint.sh"]

I find it weird that it behaves like this because I have binded/mounted a MySQL image and it does not break the mounted path.
docker-compose.yml of MySQL container
name: mysql
services:
    database:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:8.3
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX
        volumes:
            - ./container:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

Looking forward to ideas or suggestions so that I can bind/mount the /var/www path of the container where the project directory is located without breaking it ; as it currently becomes empty when mounted

What is the content of the actual Dockerfile?

@Cyclonecode updated to include some snippets in the dockerfile

Since you are using a volume for the /var/www folder in your container, why are you copying the content in the dockerfile e.g COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www? I would think this is the problem. Try removing that part from your dockerfile.

Also, I am a bit confused of why you are both using an image and a dockerfile in your docker-compose.yaml?

Let's talk about this in the chat instead: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257497/docker-directory-becomes-empty-when-binded

Does Docker: Strange behaviour of bind mount answer your question?  A bind mount always hides the content in the image and replaces it with host content, which can cause an empty directory to appear in the container.  The database containers then know how to initialize a database in an empty directory; they don't "share data" out of a prebuilt image.  The mount point appears to be overwriting the code built into the image, and if this is for development, you may find a host development environment simpler.
